# Does the GetEnumerator() in c# return a copy or the iterates the original source?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have a simple `GetEnumerator` usage.

```cs
private ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return queue.GetEnumerator();
}
```

I want to update the queue outside of this class.

So, I'm doing:

```cs
var list = _queue.GetEnumerator();
while (list.MoveNext())
{
    list.Current as string = "aaa";
}
```

**Does the `GetEnumerator()` returns a copy of the queue, or iterated the original value?**
**So while updating, I update the original?**

Thank you :)

Comment: If items inside collection are reference types, you will update the source. If items are value types, they wont get updated. Best is to test on your own.

Comment: IEnumerator.Current is readonly, you cannot update it like you are trying to do in your code. It doesn't compile

Comment: @Pac0, I want a way to enumerate and update the private queue without having the queue public. Does the GetEnumerator() in c# return a copy or the iterates the original source?

Comment: See my answer below to update elements while iterating on them.

Comment: I think there are two variants of the question, that are both being answered below. 1) Can you update the _elements_ of the collection while enumerating? 2) are you updating the actual live ConcurrentQueue (i.e., if objects are added to it while enumerating, will you also enumerate through the new ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying a collection (add, remove, replace elements) when iterating is in general risky, as one should not know how the iterator is implemented.

To add on this, a queue is made to get first element / adding element at the end, but in any case would not allow replacing an element "in the middle".

Here are two approaches that could work:

### Approach 1 - Create a new queue with updated elements

Iterate over the original queue and recreate a new collection in the process.

```
var newQueueUpdated = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var iterator = _queue.GetEnumerator();
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    newQueueUpdated.Add("aaa");
}
_queue = newQueueUpdated;
```

This is naturally done in one go by using linq `.Select` and feed the constructor of Queue with the result IEnumerable:

```
_queue  = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(_queue.Select(x => "aaa"));
```

Beware, could be resource consuming. Of course, other implementations are possible, especially if your collection is large.

### Approach 2 - Collection of mutable elements

You could use a wrapper class to enable mutation of objects stored:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create a `private ConcurrentQueue<MyObject> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<MyObject>();` instead.

And now you can mutate the elements, without having to change any reference in the collection itself:

```
var enumerator = _queue.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    enumerator.Current.Value = "aaa";
}
```

In the code above, the references stored by the container have never changed. Their *internal state* have changed, though.

In the question code, you were actually trying to change an object (string) by another object, which is not clear in the case of queue, and cannot be done through `.Current` which is readonly. And for some containers it should even be forbidden.

Comment: I just tested the code and while I'm using in custom class for the queue, this POC is working. Do you know to tell the root cause? Tnx.

Comment: Do you mean it's _not_ working? What is the error message / symptom?

Comment: @R.P Here is a working POC: https://onlinegdb.com/YNNLmzJ3f

Comment: tnx:) Do you know to tell why it's not working for primitive types? a.k.a string etc

Comment: Because the enumerated element `Current` is readonly (it's only a `get`, not `set` property), it's not meant to allow you reassigning the value in a collection. For a primitive type like string, doing this would imply "remove the reference / value stored in the collection, and replace it by a new one". [ object1 ; object2 ]  -> [ NEWObject3 ; NEW object3 ].   In the POC above, the elements in the collection are not being changed at all, [ object1 ; object2 ] -> [ object1 ; object2 ].

Comment: The rationale I imagine is this : you don't / shouldn't be concerned on where in memory / how ConcurrentQueue is storing its elements, or whether it allwos you to change them (like for any other collections, in general) so I _suppose_ designers of .NET decided to create an IEnumerator interface without the need of write access to the object. Having a readonly collection or something special should not prevent developper from enumerating them.

Comment: Another C# point in case you didn't know : you cannot _modify_ a string itself, they are _immutable_ in C#, so the only option is to replace them by a new string.

Comment: Tnx. I voted your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the exact underlying implementation.

As far as I remember, most of the built in dotnet containers use the current data, and not a snapshot.

You will likely get an exception if you modify a collection while iterating over it -- this is to protect against exactly this issue.

This is *not* the case for `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, as the `GetEnumerator` method returns a snapshot of the contents of the queue (as of .Net 4.6 - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.6#remarks))

The IEnumerator interface does not have a `set` on the `Current` property, so you cannot modify the collection this way ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.current?view=net-7.0#system-collections-ienumerator-current))

Comment: This is not true for `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some test code to see if I can modify the `ConcurrentQueue<string>` while it is iterating.

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c" });

var e = queue.GetEnumerator();

while (e.MoveNext())
{
    Console.Write(e.Current);
    if (e.Current == "b")
    {
        queue.Enqueue("x");
    }
}

e = queue.GetEnumerator(); //e.Reset(); is not supported
while (e.MoveNext())
{
    Console.Write(e.Current);
}
```

That runs successfully and produces `abcabcx`.

However, if we change the collection to a standard `List<string>` then it fails.

Here's the implementation:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c" });

var e = list.GetEnumerator();

while (e.MoveNext())
{
    Console.Write(e.Current);
    if (e.Current == "b")
    {
        list.Add("x");
    }
}

e = list.GetEnumerator();
while (e.MoveNext())
{
    Console.Write(e.Current);
}
```

That produces `ab` before throwing an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: @Engimativity - I just tested your code and you are right. Do you know to tell the root case for this?

Comment: @R.P - Root case? Do you mean root cause? And, if you do, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

For `ConcurrentQueue` this is [specifically addressed by the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.getenumerator?view=net-7.0):

> The enumeration represents a moment-in-time snapshot of the contents
> of the queue. It does not reflect any updates to the collection after
> GetEnumerator was called. The enumerator is safe to use concurrently
> with reads from and writes to the queue.

So the answer is: It acts as if it returns a copy. (It doesn't actually make a copy, but the effect is as if it was a copy - i.e. changing the original collection while enumerating it will not change the items produced by the enumeration.)

This behaviour is NOT guaranteed for other types - for example, attempting to enumerate a `List<T>` will fail if the list is modified during the enumeration.

Comment: You quote from the documentation, "The enumeration represents a moment-in-time snapshot". You cannot imply from this that "It returns a copy". There are also other means on how to return a snapshot; for example MVCC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)

Comment: @fjf2002 OK, so it acts as if it's a copy since changing the original collection will not change the elements of the enumeration. The actual implementation is a lot more efficient than if it actually made a copy!